# Assigning role in Laravel with registration

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, roles

Hi Im fairly new to Laravel and what I am trying to achieve is to assign user role to User while registering. I have successfully seeded and created my User table which contains role_id. I have created login and logout but when I try to create register for some reason the role_id that I am passing from URL parameter in my case: `{{hostAuth}}/register/1` where '1' should be role_id.

For my RegisterRequest this is how it looks currently:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:150',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:150|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        'role_id' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function getData(int $role_id): array
{

    $this->merge([
        'role_id' => $role_id,
    ]);

    return $this->validated();
}
```

Here is my Controller for that part:

```
 public function __invoke(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    User::create($request->getData(1));
}

public function register(RegisterRequest $request, int $role_id)
{
    User::create($request->getData($role_id));
}
```

And lastly web route (bcs im using SPA):

```
Route::post('/register/{role_id}', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
```

When I try to run it this is the error I'm getting:

```
  {
    "message": "The role id field is required.",
    "errors": {
        "role_id": [
            "The role id field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

When I dd the role_id I get the correct number but for some reason the role_id is not being added to the part where I validate my data, only the 3 arguments that I passed in my body show, yeah this is my body of the request as well:

```
{
"name": "test",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"password": "password",
"password_confirmation": "password"
}
```

Like I mentioned Im fairly new to Laravel so if there is a better/cleaner approach than this I'm all ears or if someone can help me figure out what I am doing here wrong. Thanks in advance :D

**Update**:
I also tried this method:

```
Route::post('/register/registerCustomer', [RegisterController::class, 'registerCustomer']);
Route::post('/register/registerMechanic', [RegisterController::class, 'registerMechanic']);
```

With:

```
public function registerCustomer(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    $role_id = $request->input('role_id', 1);

    User::create(array_merge($request->validated(), ['role_id' => $role_id]));
}

public function registerMechanic(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    $role_id = $request->input('role_id', 2);

    User::create(array_merge($request->validated(), ['role_id' => $role_id]));
}
```

Same issue:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'role_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, test@gmail.com, $2y$12$bx3UZQqOG8cO91FTz5mOeeT/
```

Comment: the form request is validated before your controller method is even excecuted ... also i wouldn't be passing the role id via a url parameter as someone could easily change that

Comment: Ah ok, but how is it being validated when I put the $this-validated(); at the end of the getData func., and added role_id before it. Also what other method of registrating users with different roles do you suggest because currently in my case I have 2 roles customer and mechanic. Do you mean something like having 2 different register controllers one for mechanic and other one for customer

Comment: Form Requests are validated when resolved ... you type-hinting a class on your controller method is called method injection (this resolves an instance of that class from the container) therefor the FormRequest is resolved from the container and passed to the controller method as an argument; in this case it never gets passed as it throws a validation exception as it is validated when resolved

Comment: Ah thx for clarification, so in my case what is the best approach to this problem. Should I create 2 different func in RegisterController and within them pass the role_id (for customer it will be 1 and for mechanic it will be 2). like public function registerCustomer and public function registerMechanic?

Comment: Ok so I tried something like this: `public function registerCustomer(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        $request->merge(['role_id' => 1]);

        User::create($request->validated());
    }`
But its the same issue

Comment: You probably don't have the `role_id` in the `$fillable` array in the user model.

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu yup you were right now it works... Thank you so much. If you want write an answer down bellow and I'll approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using the create method, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded property on your model class. The error is probably because you don't have the `role_id` there.

[From the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment-exceptions): By default, attributes that are not included in the $fillable array are silently discarded when performing mass-assignment operations. In production, this is expected behavior; however, during local development it can lead to confusion as to why model changes are not taking effect.

If you wish, you may instruct Laravel to throw an exception when attempting to fill an unfillable attribute by invoking the `preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try below >> The main steps involved modifying the `RegisterRequest` to remove the validation rule for `role_id`, since it's not part of the request body. Then, in the controller's register method, I suggested extracting the `role_id` from the URL parameter and merging it with the validated request data. This approach ensures that the `role_id` is correctly included when creating a new User instance with `User::create.`

```
public function register(RegisterRequest $request, $role_id)
{
    $userData = $request->validated();
    $userData['role_id'] = $role_id;

    User::create($userData);
}
```

Upadte your Route

```
   Route::post('/register/{role_id}', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
```